# How do you set up the integral in spherical coordinates in the following problem?

Tags: definite-integrals, spherical-coordinates

Find the volume bounded by the surface $z = x^2 + y^2$ and $x^2+y^2 = 1$ in the first quadrant. The answer is $\pi/8$ using rectangular and cylindrical coordinates and that is the correct answer, but it is $\pi/24$ when I switched to spherical coordinates, as follows, $$\int_0^{\pi/2} \int_{\pi/4}^{\pi/2} \int_0^{\cot{\phi} \csc{\phi}} \rho^2 \sin{\phi} \, d\rho \,  d\phi \, d\theta.$$ In general, how do you figure out the bounds for $\theta, \rho$ and $\phi$? I use the conversion formulas but I'm not sure how to proceed in a general way.

In rectangular and cylindrical coordinates, respectively

$$\int_0^1 \int_0^{1-x^2} x^2 + y^2 \,dy \,dx$$
$$\int_0^{\pi/2} \int_0^1 \int_0^{r^2} r \,dz\,dr\,d\theta$$

$\theta$ is sweeping angle in the $xy$-plane. $\phi$ is the sweeping angle between positive $z$-axis and the $xy$-plane.

Also, how to you finish a paragraph and enter onto the next line when you edit this (I'm new to this site)? Thanks a lot!

Comment: I edited your question. This should show how to start a new paragraph.

Comment: Why would it be different when you use spherical co-ordinates? If you do not receive the same answer, you are doing it wrong.

Comment: Also, please show us what you have so far. HINT: It is bounded by a cone with radius 1.

Comment: To start a new paragraph, two returns work or two spaces and one return.

Comment: Isn't $\theta$ the angle like latitude that ranges from $0$ to $\pi$ and has the $\sin \theta$ term in the Jacobian?

Comment: My bad! Actually the surface is an elliptic paraboloid, $z = x^2 + y^2$ and the volume is only for the first quadrant. I have corrected the problem statement.